# Как сделать посредством css тень по такому примеру?

Tags: css, css3

Ребята, подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать такую тень посредством css (box-shadow)?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5):

```css
div.drop-shadow.lifted {
    width: 300px;  
} 

.lifted {
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
}

.drop-shadow {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 2em 10px 4em;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
}

.lifted:before, .lifted:after {
    bottom: 15px;
    left: -2px;
    width: 50%;
    height: 20%;
    max-width: 300px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    box-shadow: 0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    transform: rotate(-3deg);
}

.drop-shadow:before, .drop-shadow:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -2;
}

.lifted:after {
    right: -2px;
    left: auto;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(3deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(3deg);
    transform: rotate(3deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="drop-shadow lifted">
  <p>Lifted corners</p>
</div>
```

Поиграться надо с тенями и всё.